# php echo acting strange

Tags: php, echo

this is probably so simple but still i can't get it to work
i'm using this statement:

```
echo "$num1"."+"."$num2"."=".$num1+$num2."<BR>";
```

i was expecting something like
3+3=6
but instead i get just 6

any ideas why?

Comment: You should consider retitling the question.  Everyone knows PHP acts strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put parens around the addition.  This is an order of operations conflict.

```
echo "$num1"."+"."$num2"."=".($num1+$num2)."<BR>";
```

The reason is PHP had interpreted the expression as if it were:

```
$a = "$num1"."+"."$num2"."=".$num1;
$b = $num2."<BR>";
echo $a + $b;
```

When adding strings, PHP tries to cooerce a number out of it.  The first number in the `$a` string is `$num1` or "3".  It does the same for `$b`, getting `$num2` or "3".  Thus, `$a+$b` is 6.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "$num1"."+"."$num2"."=".($num1).+.($num2)."<BR>";
```

it may work!!!